# What is the purpose of "pm2 save"?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to manage my node.js processes. Very happy with it so far.

What is the purpose of `$ pm2 save`? What is the purpose of saving a process list? I don't quite understand from the documentation.
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: Doing this will save the process list with their current environment into the dump file $PM2_HOME/.pm2/dump.pm2

Answer (score 194, accepted):

`pm2 save` takes a snapshot of your currently running Node applications. You can then restore these applications using `pm2 resurrect`.

This is useful because it means you don't have to manually restart each application when you restart pm2 (such as a machine reboot). Instead, you can just have a script that calls `pm2 resurrect` and it'll start up all the Node apps.

`pm2 resurrect` is useful to be called manually. If you want your processes to automatically start on boot, you should create a startup script with `pm2 startup`.

Comment: Note `pm2 resurrect` is useful to be called manually. If you want your processes to automatically start on boot, you should create a startup script with `pm2 startup`. More info here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: if we have multiple application running. Do you know in what order after running resurrect? I have not been able to find out in any documentation

Comment: save is hidden behind dump if you are looking for it in the help

Comment: The term "snapshot" is misleading and makes you overthink on what it does. PM2 simply describes it as "[save the app list](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#saving-the-app-list-to-be-restored-at-reboot)".

Comment: Note: `pm2 save` dumps the list of running apps to `~/pm2/dump.pm2`, and the script generated by `pm2 startup` uses it to run the apps when the server is rebooted.

Comment: `pm2 startup` is usefull, but what if my user is NOT a SUDO and I do not want the sudo to uses pm2 at all. I havve a dedicated user for these jobs, but seemingly if I execute the sscript provided by the command (without the SUDO part), it just repeats itself. IDK if it actually made it work or not

Answer (score 18):

`$ pm2 save` is used to save the pm2 process list to relaunch them after a server reboot. It comes generaly with  :

`pm2 startup` which generates Startup Script